# How to add two calenders in a page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jhtml

I am new to joomla, want to implement two calenders in a page ...

```
 From : 
    <?php
    echo JHTML::calendar('sch_from', 'sch_from', '%Y-%m-%d');
    ?>
 To :
    <?php
    echo JHTML::calendar('sch_to', 'sch_to', '%Y-%m-%d');
    ?>
```

But first calendar only working... is there any issue in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you have supplied is wrong.

The function has implemented with following arguments:

```
public static function calendar($value, $name, $id, $format = '%Y-%m-%d', $attribs = null)
```

It should be like this:

```
JHTML::calendar('', 'sch_from', 'sch_from', '%Y-%m-%d');
JHTML::calendar('', 'sch_to', 'sch_to', '%Y-%m-%d');
```